# Why can't I reinstall Module Magento?

Tags: sql, magento, module, installation

I have a module in magento, and the script setup module. Now I want to re-run this script and this module. I deleted the setup of this module in core_resource, and access magento. But the module is not reinstalled. The database of this module isn't deleted, althought I have DROP TABLE IF EXIST in scripts. And in the core_resource, the setup of this module not exists, it is really deleted. So I think the setup not run. But this module still work normally with old sql and no setup field in core_resource.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your Magento configuration cache to trigger an re-run of an setup resource migration script. This cache clearing lets Magento see the version of a module has changed.

Also, you might consider using the [`n98-magerun`](http://magerun.net/) command line tool -- it has a number of commands for manually running setup resource migration scripts.

Answer (score 0):

manually drop table,

and then remove core_resource row record,

and then run any page again